# XmlTextWriter. Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу так как этот файл используется другим процессом

Tags: c#, xml

У меня есть 3 XML файла,из которых нужно периодически считывать информацию и стоить treeview'ы исходя из нее. Я делаю это так - при необходимости что-то считать, запускаются 3 потока, каждый из которых пытается прочитать файл( `if (XMLReady[index] == true)` проверяет была ли уже записана информация в файл). В первый раз все работает отлично, но при повторном вызове получаю исключение System.IO.IOException: 'Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "***", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.'. Почему так - не понимаю, ведь поток и сам XmlTextReader закрыты. Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

```
 public void readXML(System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeView, string fileName,int index)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (XMLReady[index] == true)
            {
                using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(fileName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => treeView.BeginUpdate());
                        TreeNode parentNode = null;

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                            {
                                if (reader.Name == XmlNodeTag)
                                {
                                    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
                                    bool isEmptyElement = reader.IsEmptyElement;
                                    int attributeCount = reader.AttributeCount;
                                    if (attributeCount > 0)
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < attributeCount; i++)
                                        {
                                            reader.MoveToAttribute(i);

                                            SetAttributeValue(newNode, reader.Name, reader.Value);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (parentNode != null)
                                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => parentNode.Nodes.Add(newNode));
                                    else
                                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => treeView.Nodes.Add(newNode));

                                    if (!isEmptyElement)
                                    {
                                        parentNode = newNode;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                            {
                                if (reader.Name == XmlNodeTag)
                                {
                                    parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                            {
                            }
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.None)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                            {
                                parentNode.Nodes.Add(reader.Value);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Visit(treeView.Nodes);
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => treeView.EndUpdate());
                        reader.Dispose();
                        reader.Close();
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Вызов потоков

```
new Thread(() =>  readXML(tvMission, "./Knowledge//MyTreeView.xml", 0)).Start();
new Thread(() =>  readXML(tvRestruction, "./Knowledge//MyTreeView1.xml", 1)).Start();
new Thread(() =>  readXML(tvAttr, "./Knowledge//MyTreeView2.xml", 2)).Start();
```

Comment: Проблема в том что вы работате с одним файлом 3мя потоками , когда один поток открыл  файл в это же время другой пытаетеся его октрыть и вы получате ошибку, исправить это вам поможет `mutex`

Comment: @OXYGEN  3 разных файла, по одному в каждом потоке. Я добавил код,в котором я вызываю потоки в вопрос.